# How do I conditionally merge rows based on rows difference in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, rows, difference

I have gone through some relevant merging questions but my problem is slightly different from the existing ones. I have a table in my  PostgreSQL 9.5 database containing four columns i.e., Segment (unique group), height (numeric), lower_limit (numeric) and upper_limit (numeric). The sample data is as follows:

```
Segment height  lower_limit upper_limit
A       19.3    112         142
A       19.3    142         172
A       20.3    172         202
A       20.3    202         232
A       19.3    232         262
A       19.3    262         292
B       22.1    203         233
B       22.1    233         263
B       22.1    263         293
B       22.1    293         323
B       22.1    323         353
B       22.1    353         383
C       18.9    136         166
C       18.9    166         196
C       18.9    196         226
C       27.1    286         316
C       27.1    316         346
C       6.5     346         376
C       6.5     376         406
```

I need to conditionally merge rows based on the difference of height values. I would try to explain in steps:

- Starting from the first height, check if the difference between preceding and succeeding row is less or equal to 1
- If condition fulfills merge those rows with lower limit of first row and upper limit of merged row
- if all rows are merged in a group then select the most common height with lower limit of first and upper limit of last merged row
- repeat this for other groups

  Based on above, the desired output could be like:

  `Segment   height    lower_limit     upper_limit 
  A          19.3      112                292
  B          22.1      203                383
  C          18.9      136                226
  C          27.1      286                346
  C          6.5       346                406`

Can somebody help me so that I could conditionally merge rows based on height difference values?

Comment: is there a column to specify the order?

Comment: I added order by grp line at the end of code. I am getting 5 rows according to desired output but in this manner: C, A, B, C, C. Please see the desired output.

Comment: add order by `segment,grp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming lower_limit column can be used for ordering, you can use

```
select segment,mode() within group(order by height),min(lower_limit),max(upper_limit) 
from (select t.*
      ,sum(case when abs(height-prev) <= 1 then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by segment order by lower_limit) as grp
      from (select t.*
            ,lag(height) over(partition by segment order by lower_limit) as prev
            from tbl t
           ) t
    ) t
group by segment,grp
```

Comment: I modified last two lines. I added: group by grp, segment Order by grp, segment. I got A, B, C, C, C as desired. All values are fine except the first segment A. For A; it gives, 20.3, 112, 292. Any idea why ?

Comment: @JibranKhan ..check the edit..using `mode` gives you the most frequent height per segment and grp..which is what you need.

Comment: I have one question, If I have one row or two rows containing zero then how can I break that row/rows into a separate group with their lower and upper limit. I think changes need to be made in this line: sum(case when abs(height-prev) <= 1 then 0 else 1 end) - OR- you suggest me to ask this as a separate question?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   -- setting reset points
>   with  b as
>   (
>       select segment, height, lower_limit, upper_limit, 
>              case when lag(height) over (partition by segment order by segment, height) is null
>                        or abs(height - lag(height) over (partition by segment order by segment, height)) > 1
>                   then 1 end as is_reset
>       from   foo
>   )
>      -- setting groups
>      , c as
>      (
>          select segment, height, lower_limit, upper_limit,
>                 sum(is_reset) over (order by segment, height) as grp
>          from b
>      )
>        -- finding most common height
>            select segment, mode() within group (order by height),
>                   min(lower_limit) as lower_limit, 
>                   max(upper_limit) as upper_limit
>            from c
>            group by segment, grp
> ```
>
> ```
> segment |  mode | lower_limit | upper_limit
> :------ | ----: | ----------: | ----------:
> A       | 19.30 |         112 |         292
> B       | 22.10 |         203 |         383
> C       |  6.50 |         346 |         406
> C       | 18.90 |         136 |         226
> C       | 27.10 |         286 |         346
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e95bd17e74ab30c99ff883e96c9aa8e9)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tested your code in dbfiddle. It worked fine there. Exactly same table is in my Postgres db but it returned six rows i.e., A, B, C, C, C, C. One row C (18.9, 136, 226) is returned twice. Any idea why?

Comment: execute the first select and be sure it returns the correct order.

Comment: Well, I reformated the whole code to make sure i am not making any mistake but still the same result.

Comment: does this query `select segment, height, lower_limit, upper_limit, row_number() over (partition by segment order by (select 1)) id
    from foo` returns the correct order?

Comment: No it doesn't. One row C, 18.9..... is at the bottom of result which is not correct if you look at the sample data.

Comment: does your table any field to use as `order by`?

Comment: It didn't have the primary key. So, I order by segments.

Comment: Yes, now it returned 5 rows as expected. But, heights are returned as 19.3, 22.1, 6.5, 18.9, 27.1 which is not as desired output. Please see above.